# Taking first N items from two combined iterators?

Tags: python-3.x, python-itertools

I've got two iterables (i1 and i2).  Each one is producing items sorted in order of a key, with both iterables using the same key.  I want to get the first N items, still sorted by the key, from the combined iterations.  If I was willing to completely consume both iterables, I could do:

```
l = list(i1) + list(i2)
l.sort()
l[:n]
```

but I know I'm only going to need a small fraction of that.  Is there some neat way to do this using just itertools?

Comment: This is a simple case of what `heapq.merge()` excels at.

Comment: Ah, cool.  That's exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Tim Peters's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62976275/taking-first-n-items-from-two-combined-iterators/62976364#comment111366078_62976275) to use `heapq.merge()`.